# How to mix non-standard and standard evaluation in arguments to interaction(...) inside ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, interaction, nse

I am seeking for a way to use NSE inside argument (in this case, intersect) in `dplyr` using `rlang` package.

Data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(time=as.factor(c(10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20)),
                 cost=as.factor(c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40)),
                 type=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
                 value=c(40,20,25,10,80,50,30,60,15,70,80,10,50,20,30,40))

## Set variables for NSE
a <- "time"
b <- "cost"
c <- "type"
d <- "value"

nse_a <- sym(a)
nse_b <- sym(b)
nse_c <- sym(c)
nse_d <- sym(d)
```

I can plot properly in SE.

```
## Plot in SE
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=cost, y=value, group=interaction(time,type), color=time, linetype=type)) + geom_line(size=1.2)
```

[image]

However, when I use NSE, it occurs an error:

```
## Plot in NSE
df %>% ggplot(aes_(x=nse_b, y=nse_d, group=interaction(nse_a,nse_c), color=nse_a, linetype=nse_c)) + geom_line(size=1.2)

Error: unique.default(x, nmax = nmax)
unique() applies only to vectors
```

It works if I remove `group=intersection(...)`. I suppose the reason may be using NSE in a nested argument 'intersect(...)' inside `aes_`.

Do you have any solution to avoid this error?

I searched similar topics and tried to apply some examples such as unquoting by !!nse_a but it did not not work. I am new to 'NSE' and still do not well understand its manipulation manner.

Comment: care to explain NSE and SE?

Comment: Why are you using NSE anyway? You are working with data frame columns, it seems like an unnecessary layer of complexity. Are you writing your own function? Is it really such a gain not to just put the relevant column names in quotes?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Though there are limited number of columns in this example, a number of fields are set in the actual data frame which should be tabulated based on the needs. Actually I set a function and change definition of, in this example, a, b, c, d, for flexible tabulation. That is why I need to use non-standard evaluation as it allows to chagne variables in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass quoted arguments to `aes_()`, so the `interaction` has to be quoted, but it itself needs unquoted arguments (not really sure about the terminology here, sorry for any confusion)

```
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)


interact <- quo(interaction(!!nse_a, !!nse_c))

df %>%
ggplot(aes_(x=nse_b, 
            y=nse_d, 
            group=interact, 
            color=nse_a, 
            linetype=nse_c)) + 
    geom_line(size=1.2)

# or equally

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes_(x=nse_b, 
              y=nse_d, 
              group=quo(interaction(!!nse_a, !!nse_c)), 
              color=nse_a, 
              linetype=nse_c)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.2)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Base R's `interaction` doesn't work with `rlang`, which in general is for the tidyverse only. (EDIT: but see GGamba's answer which shows how to use `!!` to pass NSE arguments in to standard functions.)

Almost certainly the simplest solution is to create the interaction variable yourself.

```
df$mygroup <- interaction(df$time, df$type)
```

Now use `mygroup` inside your `ggplot` call.

By doing this you avoid NSE hell.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However I need to keep using NSE as plotting should be done by changing its variables based on the needs.
Anyway thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Right, but why not just do e.g. `df$mygroup <- interaction(df[[var1]], df[[var2]])` where `var1` and `var2` are passed into your function?

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and let me try to apply it in the actual use case to fully understand it. I suppose I still need further investigation on it.